# XLOOKUP [if_not_found] parameter

Tags: excel, xlookup

XLOOKUP don't suppose to show `[if_not_found]` before `[match mode]` parameter ?

[image: [if_not_found] not showing..]

- I have office 2019, but one thing is very unclear to me.. I had to insall the XLOOKUP dll, because my excel didn't have it.. and I red that it only comes with office 365- so I insalled it according to here:link look at "show more".

Answer (score 0):

Never seen that argument in LOOKUP() or HLOOKUP() or even VLOOKUP()

always targetvalue, array, indexcol or row and match....

But xlookup() does show the argument you are quoting:
[image]

So, it may just be your version of Excel, is it up to date? Because it works on mine.

Comment: Thanks. I have office 2019, but one thing is very unclear to me.. I had to insall the `XLOOKUP` dll, cuase my excel didn't have it.. and I red that it ony comes with office 365- so I insalled it according to here:[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-E_nfxqc-Q&ab_channel=STB81) look at "show more".

Comment: do you know why?

Comment: Do I know why? as in why it works on mine? Office 365...

Comment: yes. I saw that there are bunch of functions only supported in office 365. do You happen to know if there is a way to add these function to office 2019?